# Can't get my FB events whereas I have some

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I design an app who retreive my facebook's event.
I successful connect to my account, I request `"/me/events"`, FB responds `200` with `data: []` but when I log myself on Facebook, I can see I have 2 events incoming. What did I missed ?

Here is some pieces of my code :

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Calendar API Maxime</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Connecté en tant que : <span class='username'>Anonyme</span></p>
    <ul class="events">

    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '376225472791830',
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.10'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

        FB.login(function() {
          FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
              console.log(response);
            } else {
              console.error(response.error);
            }
          })
        })
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does `console.log(response)` show you?

Comment: It responds: `data: []`

Comment: in the docs it says - `Login Review: user_events - To use the user_events permission you need to submit your app for review.` - see here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ - maybe that's why

Comment: You neglected to ask the user for the necessary permission.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald that applies when it comes to “normal” users. But so that you can implement and test your stuff properly _before_ you submit it for review, every user with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) can be asked for any permission at any time, reviewed or not.

Comment: OK! I understand now ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cbroe But I use my personnal account to retreive my events and I am Administrator on my app.

Comment: That does absolutely not matter one bit. You need to grant the necessary permission to your app. Whether you are the app admin, or just a regular user, makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @CBroe That was that. I add to do this : ```FB.login( callback, {scope: "user_events})``` TY :)